# Different types of Power MOSFETS

Tags: power

Can you please tell me the difference between DMOSFET and VMOSFET? 
 Or can suggest any good ebook regarding power MOSFET?

Answer (score 2):

Google turned this up in a couple of seconds:

http://www.colorado.edu/physics/phys3330/phys3330_fa05/pdfdocs/AN101FETintro.pdf

It looks very good.

Both types are described.

Comment: Thank You very much for ur help,I had already the above article when i Googled POWER MOSFET,I need behaviourial and characteristic difference between the two.
I have referred fairchild ,ST,Omega data sheets.And I found only info in the following link:
http://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/book/book/chapter7/ch7_8.htm